# Outlook: open attachment externally

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, attachments

In Outlook 2016 if I single-click an attachment, it opens in the Reading Pane, while double-clicks open them in the matching external program.
Sometimes Windows finds my double-click too slow, interprets it as a single click, and opens the attachment in the Reading Pane, sometimes taking minutes.

Can I somehow turn off this behavior, so the attachment either opens externally or not at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off attachment preview via Options> Trust Center> Trust Center Settings.. > Attchment Handling, select the checkbox of Turn off Attachment Preview:

[image: turn off attachment preview]